# sfdx force:source:deploy Pushing All Files

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm using a sample project I generated in VS Code, and added a couple of lightning components and lightning web components.

In testing some scripting, I am trying to accomplish a selective sfdx lightning component deploy like

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/default/aura/mycomponent1/componentname.cmp
```

But! When I attempt this, all of the other artifacts get deployed as well.

The documentation says you can specify a path to a single file, but it doesn't appear to work that way. When I do a retrieve, all of the components files are pulled down :(

Output of `sfdx -v`:

```
sfdx-cli/7.5.0-e6ca93eee8 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3
```

Just a case of doing-it-wrong?

Comment: I think this is by design.  All Lightning Aura Components get deployed together, whereby other types of metadata can be deployed individually

Comment: Brian is exactly right (and could write the comment as an answer). `force:source:deploy` uses the Metadata API, and the MDAPI [`AuraDefinitionBundle` type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm) includes the different elements as base64Binary blobs, rather than as child XML types.

Comment: Ah very good to know, thank you both for the clarification